# How do you add textboxes to Oracle APEX reports?

Tags: oracle, textbox, report, editing, oracle-apex

I'm generating a matrix report in Oracle APEX. I've got the values displaying properly, but when I click the "Edit button", I want all the cells to turn into textboxes. 
I know that you can do this by changing some settings in the Report Attributes, but the problem is my matrix report is dynamic, which means that I do not know in advance how many rows and columns my matrix report would be.
I hope my sample can explain more what I need. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but I think Apex 4.0 might have something like this with editable Interactive Reports.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to go with using a Tabular Form on a view that I created in the PL/SQL database. There are a few complications with dynamic data but I'm currently trying to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Apex 4.0 will have what is currently being called 'Worksheet' which will bring in native dynamic editing of tabular forms. You can have a look at including ExtJS, like one oracle guru has done: http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=200801:2006 He's got dynamic content entering with a 'popup' field.. but his editable grid page is 404'ing at the moment.. unsure where it is.

Answer (score 0):

use APEX_ITEM API to achieve this.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192